# compile 'io.grpc:grpc...' fail in demo project

Tags: android, grpc, grpc-java

I downloaded android simple demo helloworld client project from here, I not modify code:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/android/helloworld

When building the gradle I get error:

```
Error:(58, 13) Failed to resolve: io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.8.1-SNAPSHOT
Error:(57, 13) Failed to resolve: io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.8.1-SNAPSHOT
Error:(59, 13) Failed to resolve: io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.8.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Gradle:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/android/helloworld/app/build.gradle

I am following the instructions here:
https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/android.html

But I'm not clear if I have to do some more steps to make it work. I thought that the gradle when you put 'compile' the libraries are downloaded from the repositories automatically.

I have a windows machine and I have not installed any grpc libraries in it, do I have to download and install something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to checkout a specific release tag: `git checkout v1.8.0`

I've [sent out a PR](https://github.com/grpc/grpc.github.io/pull/608) to fix this. The [Android quickstart](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/android.html#download-the-example) didn't suffer from this problem.